# Cloud Functions region specification error

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to deploy a Cloud Function written in TypeScript using a Firestore trigger. The script works without any problems. However I will need to specify the execution region, to respect my RGPD I need the functions to be executed in europe-west1. I have looked at the documentation on the subject, it is specified to add ".region" in the function however this generates an error that you will find attached.The error obtained is "error TS2339: Property 'region' does not exist on type 'DocumentBuilder. I would like to point out that I don't have any errors in VSC locally it's only that I'm connected to Firebase.

Index.ts

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();

export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
  .document('orders/{orderId}')
  .region('europe-west1')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {


    const order = snapshot.data();

    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(order.seller)
      .collection('tokens')
      .get();

    const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Order!',
        body: `you sold a ${order.product} for ${order.total}`,
        icon: 'your-icon-url',
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  });
```

package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you for your future answer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic52a.png)

Comment: Please don't show images of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region), region specification comes right after the `functions` builder declaration, like this:

```
export const sendToDevice = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .firestore
  .document('orders/{orderId}')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {
```

Notice that the region specification is immediately after `functions`.  What you have is much later in the builder, which is not valid.

Be sure to use the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions) to figure out what methods are valid at each stage during a build of a function.

Comment: Thank you ! it made sense indeed.